# The best way to display visitors online

Tags: php, mysql

I've been thinking about this. A site with 10000 visitors online 24/7, it can't be good to run a query to select all rows with lastaction > time() - 300 (5 minutes ago)?
This query would be run thousands of times per minute.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE status = 1` (assuming 1 = logged in)

Comment: The "best" way depends entirely on your individual circumstances DB schema/server power etc... as you've provided none this question is effectively answerable.

Comment: best - random number generator within some pre-set range - least overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something that caches like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)).

Then, make this query only run if your cache has expired

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE status = 1 // assume status = 1 = logged in here
```

Like so:

```
$memcache = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
// it is highly important to firewall off your memcache port.
$contents = memcache_get($memcache, 'user_count');
if ($contents === false) {
    $count = /* query here */
    memcache_set($memcache, 'user_count', $count, 0, 2);
} else {
    $count = htmlspecialchars($contents);
    // note: slightly unsafe in that there is no security. always escape. 
}
```